# Android background thread and cpu frequency

Tags: android, multithreading, cpu, frequency

In my android App I run a background thread that continuously operates on images from the camera preview.

A camera preview image is only fetched after the thread has completed processing of the previous preview image.

According to DDMS systrace, the device lowers the CPU frequency of the cores after some seconds (images are processed continuously):

[image: cpu frequency]

(The library I am using has built-in parallel support which is why both Cores are active).

This is a problem for my App, because what previously took 400ms to compute, now takes 1200ms.

If I feed the preview images by hand (e.g. by button click) I do not have that problem. The device always gives full power until the thread finishes processing (400ms).

I have searched the net but did not find any information. Does android lower my thread's priority if it never goes to sleep?